# Structure field type - how do I get additional entry data to display?

Tags: channel-entries, structure, fieldtype

I'm using the Structure field type as pictured.

[image: Structure]

The only thing my template will output is {field_name}, which yields:

http://domain.com/my-structure-url

But I need to access/display more info. If I could get the entry_id or url_title, I could run a channel entries loop, but it appears that's not available. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get more info from the entry, I think a 'Relationship' field or Playa could be your best option.

Comment: Yeah, I considered this - but there are a number of entries with the same title. I would need a way to show the entry's context in structure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the docs?

http://buildwithstructure.com/tags#tag_global_variables

I believe you want to utilize one of these Structure global variables. Something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}

    {title} - Stuff! - {entry_id} - Things!

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: {structure:page:entry_id} gets the current page's entry id, but I need that info from the field itself.

Comment: Had to use a plugin to get this data out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the query module. Find the ID of your Structure field (shown in the Channel Fields table) and then enter the following in your template, replacing the field_id_25 with your field ID. This will output the entry id of the selected entry.

```
{exp:query sql="select field_id_25 from exp_channel_data where entry_id={structure:page:entry_id}"}{field_id_25}{/exp:query}
```